# Batch rearranging and renaming filenames in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

I need help with rearranging and renaming a bunch of files in PowerShell. 
I want to change from:

YYYY_Project name_City**_Category**.jpg

to

YYYY**_Category**_Project name_City.jpg

The years, categories, project names and cities are of course all different.

Please be gentle, I'm new to PowerShell and regex.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [Tour] and read at least [Ask] if you haven't done this already. Then you should use the seach field on top of this site and search for "_Powershell rename files_". You will find more than enough answers to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have an item like this:

```
 get-item '.\YYYY_Project name_City_Category.jpg'


    Directory: C:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                 
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                 
-a----         6/8/2020  10:12 AM              8 YYYY_Project name_City_Category.jpg
```

This is a `FileInfo` object which has a number of properties, one of which is `BaseName` which gives us the filename without extension.

```
PS> $file = get-item '.\YYYY_Project name_City_Category.jpg'
PS> $File.BaseName
YYYY_Project name_City_Category
```

We can call the `.Split()` method on the BaseName property to split on every instance of the `_` underscore character, like so:

```
PS> $File.BaseName.Split('_')
YYYY
Project name
City
Category
```

We can then assign those to variables like this:

```
$FileSegments = $File.BaseName.Split('_')
$YearPart = $FileSegments[0]
$ProjPart = $FileSegments[1]
$CityPart = $FileSegments[2]
$CatgPart = $FileSegments[3]
```

We can then reassemble them in our desired order like this:

```
$newName = $YearPart + "_" + $CatgPart + "_" + $ProjPart + "_" + $CityPart + $file.Extension
write-host $newName
YYYY_Category_Project name_City.jpg
```

So, you'd put it all together like this.  If you like the results, remove `-WhatIf`

```
$files = Get-ChildItem C:\PathTo\Your\Directory\*.jpg
ForEach ($file in $files){
    $FileSegments = $File.BaseName.Split('_')
    $YearPart = $FileSegments[0]
    $ProjPart = $FileSegments[1]
    $CityPart = $FileSegments[2]
    $CatgPart = $FileSegments[3]

    $newName = $YearPart + "_" + $CatgPart + "_" + $ProjPart + "_" + $CityPart + $file.Extension
    write-host $newName
    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newName -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: great job. Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked (and revealed all my inconsistencies).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a complex Regex for this, just some understanding of how to get the files in a folder using [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and how [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7) works.

Something like this should do it

```
$sourcePath = 'Folder\To\Where\The\Files\Are'

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Filter '*.jpg' -File | Rename-Item -NewName {
    # split the file's BaseName into 4 pieces at the underscore
    $year, $project, $city, $category = $_.BaseName -split '_', 4
    # use the -f Format operator to stitch the parts together in a new order
    # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#format-operator--f
    '{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}{4}' -f $year, $category, $project, $city, $_.Extension
}
```

Comment: I used to say SO is not a free code writing service but obviously I was wrong. ;-)

Comment: @Olaf No, you're not wrong. I guess it's because we're all getting a bit bored being confined to our homes.. Mea culpa..

Answer (score 0):

One liner version of the split and join idea:

```
dir *_*_*_*.jpg | ren -new {((($_.basename -split '_')[0,3,1,2]) -join '_') +'.jpg'} -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
"Item:       C:\Users\admin\foo\YYYY_Project name_City_Category.jpg 
Destination: C:\Users\admin\foo\YYYY_Category_Project name_City.jpg".
```